# Django form_valid method

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, django-forms

In my form's view I wonder what if I don't add **product_form.save** method in the code below and what if I add that:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        product_form = form.save(commit=False)
        product_form.user = self.request.user
        product_form.save() # what if I delete this?
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: As I see it saves the form without that line either, but what is the difference between including that line of code?

Comment: In  what view do you use this? If it is a `CreateView`/`UpdateView`, it is fine. For a `FormView` it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In  what view do you use this? If it is a [**`CreateView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) or [**`UpdateView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView), it is fine. For a (simple) [**`FormView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView), it is not since a `FormView` does not save the form.

You however do not need to save the form with `commit=False` to retrieve the instance. A simple one-liner to set the user is:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class MyCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    # …
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

The name `product_form` in `product_form = form.save(commit=False)` is also somewhat misleading: the `.save()` method does not return a `Form`, but a `Product` object, hence it is a `Product`. But you do not need to save that product in the database, since a `CreateView` and `UpdateView` will call the `.save()` function of the form to save the model together with many-to-many relations that are specified in the form.